# No output after peakcalling of mtDNA with MACS2

Tags: linux, bioinformatics

I am new to the CHIP-seq analysis.
I am basically trying to call peaks using MACS 2 with the proccessed data of mitochondrial DNA only in bedgraph format given in the accession number GSE48176 under the link https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE48176.
I used three treated samples and three control samples in the analysis, with the command "macs2 callpeak -f BED -g hs  --mfold 2 30 --nomodel -t GSM1171656_Hela-TFAM-12228.36mers.v0.chrM.wig.sorted.bed GSM1171657_Hela-TFAM-12277.36mers.v0.chrM.wig.sorted.bed GSM1171658_Hela-TFAM-12526.36mers.v0.chrM.wig.sorted.bed GSM1171659_Hela-TFAM-PrepK-12332.36mers.v0.chrM.wig.sorted.bed -c  GSM1171652_Hela-Input-12229.36mers.v0.chrM.wig.sorted.bed GSM1171653_Hela-Input-12278.36mers.v0.chrM.wig.sorted.bed GSM1171654_Hela-Input-12527.36mers.v0.chrM.wig.sorted.bed GSM1171655_Hela-Input-PrepK-12333.36mers.v0.chrM.wig.sorted.bed -n TFAM-12228.36mers.v0chrM"
I should have many peaks as Circos plot given in the paper "Genome-Wide Analysis Reveals Coating of the Mitochondrial Genome by TFAM".But All I got from MACS2 callpeak output was only 1 200bp fragment long peak. Nothing other than that. Although I used the call MACS2 callpeak function according to the description of the paper, I am getting no output.
Is there something I am doing wrong with the command?
If someone Could clarify the problem, it would be great! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUuCh.png)

I tried MACS2 callpeak function as given in the paper, and expected as many peaks as given in the circos plot.

Answer (score 0):

These are all bedGraph files meaning that they're not suitable for peak calling with the macs2 caller as you do it.

What macs2 expects is one line in the BED file per read, but bedGraph is a summarized pipeup format in which reads are aggregated into a coverage value displayed in the fourth column, covering the intervals in columns 1-3. In short, your command together with these files is wrong, poor results are expected. You will need to download the raw data, align them and then call peaks.

Alternatively, check whether the ReMap2022 database covers this dataset, you might be able to download peak lists from there.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. As you have said bedgraph files are not suitable as input files for MACS2 peakcall, which is why I converted the processed files from the given GSE number to BED files by converting them to "bigwig files" and then subsequently to "wig files" and then finally to "BED files" to use the BED files for MACS2 callpeak function. This didn't work as I mentioned previously. Or, are you saying converting the processed BedGraph file to BED files is not the right strategy, and instead I should start from the raw FASTQ files to finally convert them to BED files?